# Lists in VBscript return object

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a vbscript function that looks something like this:

```
Public Function fnGetXLSFileCount()
Dim fso, src, folder, file, fileList

    Set fileList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    src = "\\myserver\myfolder" 
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(src) 
    For Each file In folder.files 
        If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file)) = "xlsx" Then 
            fileList.Add file.name
        End If 
    Next 
    Set fnGetXLSFileCount = fileList

End Function
```

As you can see I'm creating an ArrayList and then adding all the names of excel files that exist in a specified folder.

I then call this function and use the Set operator to specify that I'm expecting an object to be returned.

```
Set XLSFileList = fnGetXLSFileCount
```

When I check the count on the object it seems to be correct.
When I try to pull the names out there is nothing there.  What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
For each file in XLSFileList
    name = file.Item(0)
Next
```

Comment: Yes, the () is optional there.

Answer (score 1):

The `For Each` loop already enumerates the items of the collection. And since you assign just the names to the collection you simply use the loop variable to get the name:

```
For Each file In XLSFileList
    name = file
Next
```

The `Item` property can be used to directly access a specific item from the collection:

```
WScript.Echo XLSFileList.Item(0)
```

Comment: I feel so stupid.  I was just over complicating it. Thank you.